# Close sockets in IOCP (close some sockets in IOCP)

Tags: sockets, networking, iocp

There are sockets in IOCP  ..group A,B

A,B are working for receiving data.
But when I close sockets in group A like below.

shutdown...
closesocket...

Sockets in group B seems like corrupted and stopped working.
If anyone has experienced similar symptom.
Give me some advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "group A, B"? Can we see some code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Problem is worker threads terminated unintentionally.
My previous code like below

```
while (GetQuededCompletionStatus...)
{
    // Do io related works
}
```

Problem is 'GetQueuedCompiletionStatus' function returns IO status TRUE/FALSE
When socket closed It returns FALSE. So entire while loop exited and thread closed.
This fixed like below

```
while (1)
{
   BOOL iostatus = GetQueuedCompletionStatus...
   if (iostatus==TRUE)
   {
       // Do IO works
   }
}
```

Maybe this skeleton is basic IOCP worker thread loop